# Checking a list of objects against another list of objects

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a user profile that contains a manytomany field which points to a set of favorite objects.

I have a queryset that returns an set of those types of objects, independent of the favorites (though it may contain favorites).

What I want to do is this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <p>{% if user.get_profile.favorites contains object %} Unfavorite {% else %} Favorite {% endif %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But thus far, I cannot find an easy to way do this. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator)

Comment: That's got to be the shortest helpful response I've ever gotten.

Comment: Until the link breaks then it's completely useless. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `object in user.get_profile.favorites`?

In any case, do your processing in your views, not in your templates.

Comment: The only reason I want to do it in the template is because I want to render one batch of html or the other. The above text is simplified.

Comment: That doesn't prevent making the choice in your view, or even make it preferable to make the choice in your template.